# Get an error, when screen is too big

Tags: java, android, bitmap, illegalargumentexception

I recently uploaded an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.krissini.server) to the google play store. It works for some devices, but not for big ones like the nexus 7. I get following stacktraces:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:667)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:634)
    at de.krissini.server.Player.<init>(Player.java:26)
    at de.krissini.server.GamePanel.surfaceCreated(GamePanel.java:64)
```

Here is the refered code. GamePanel:

```
@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        score = 0;
        fuel = 50;
        bg = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.grassbg1), 1000);
        player = new Player(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.helicopter), 132, 47, 3);  // line 64
        scoreStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        smoke = new ArrayList<Smokepuff>();
        smokestartTime = System.nanoTime();
        missles = new ArrayList<Missle>();
        missleStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

        // start game loop
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }
```

Player:

```
public Player(Bitmap res, int w, int h, int numFrames) {
        x = 100;
        y = GamePanel.HEIGHT / 2;
        dy = 0;
        score = 0;
        height = h;
        width = w;
        spritesheet = res;
        Bitmap[] image = new Bitmap[numFrames];
        for(int i = 0; i<image.length; i++){
            image[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(spritesheet, i*width, 0, width, height); // line 62
        }

        animation.setFrames(image);
        animation.setDelay(10);
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
```

What can I do to get rid of this error? I appreciate every answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(spritesheet, i*width, 0, width, height);
```

is invalid for this magic numbers  **132, 47**

since  `x + width must be <= bitmap.width()`

Comment: 132 , 47 are the width and height of my image

Comment: but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect, but I changed to this. works.

```
Bitmap[] image = new Bitmap[numFrames];
        try{
        for(int i = 0; i<image.length; i++){
            image[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(spritesheet, i*width, 0, width, height);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            image = new Bitmap[1];
            image[0] = Bitmap.createBitmap(spritesheet, 0, 0, 63, height);
        }
```

But why did it work on some devices only?